# Whatsapp does not show a contact. Tried "everything"

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have an Xperia Z1 with Android 4.2.2 and the latest version of Whatsapp.
There is at least one contact whom I am sure has got Whatsapp but is not shown in Whatsapp contacts.

The contact is in my phone's address book, with country code.
"Show all contacts" is selected, no hidden contact, auto sync is on; I manually synced, refreshed, deleted and reinstalled both contacts and app.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as said, I had tried everything, Refresh included, the international code for my number and all contacts numbers, everything.
The problem was much more idiot: my friend finally told me that the number connected to Whatsapp was the old one. As it was associated to the email, it was not letting the new number appear.
Something like that.
I still do not understand how this is possible,
I mean, somebody uses Whatsapp with a number, then changes number but not email, and start sending messages through the new number, but does not appear with that number because the email is registered with the old number?
Crazy. How can then this person send messages from the new number?
Complicated.
Anyway.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Some options you could try:

**Option 1**

Tap on [image: WhatsApp Message Icon] icon and then go to  `Menu > Refresh`.

**Option 2**

Tap on [image: WhatsApp Message Icon] icon and then go to  `Menu > Help`. There are some instructions their which you can try and tap on `Show invisible contacts`.

**Option 3**

Follow this article from WhatsApp to try to troubleshoot: **[How do I add contacts to WhatsApp?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/21082107)**

Answer (score 1):

Well you just need to edit the contact by adding +(country code) follow by the existing contact number.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. My contacts from abroad did not have a plus before the country code, so they were not parsed. Just add a plus and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Is it an international contact? Whatsapp sometimes doesn't add 00316-* numbers for me but it does add 06-*.

Answer (score -1):

Mobile number should have+area code

Comment: OP wrote: *The contact is in my phone's address book, with country code.* So if even the country code is in, area code is in as well (or OP would have noticed trouble when trying to call that contact). Or did you mean something different?